# Skewed distribution for a given range

Tags: python, distribution, scipy.stats

I need to generate a skewed distribution for a given range (eg: low= 1, high =10) and size = 100.
stats.skewnorm can produce a skewed distribution, but it does not take in the parameter for lower and upper bound.
Can someone please help me with it.

```
def skewed_data(low, high, number):
    skew_parameter = 5
    data = skewnorm.rvs(skew_parameter, loc=1, scale=1, size=number)
    data = np.round(data,0).astype(int)
    return data

result_data = skewed_data(1, 10,100)

bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
plt.hist(response, bins, alpha=1, label='histogram')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

the histogram plot of the result data is shown below (all the result data are between 1 to 5, whereas I would like it to be distributed between 1 to 10 and right skewed.

[image]

Comment: what does your output currently look like? and what does it need to look like. Please provide an example of both.

Comment: @TaylorCochran: the resulted data is  in between 0 to 3. I like it to be distributed between 1 and 10 and right skewed.

Comment: @Taylor: I have edited the question for clarity. I changed loc = 1 now, the result is in between 1 and 5, whereas I want it to be distributed between 1 and 10 (for example, or 10 to 100) as start and end is specified in the argument.

Comment: where is distribution defined?

Comment: @TaylorCochran: skew_parameter defines the skewness. But I am not sure how to define the distribution.

Comment: so what I'm getting at here is that you have a number of variables that are not defined in your example. This makes reproducing the issue you are having harder. i.e. `distribution` is being passed into your func `np.round()` and neither is `response` defined in this example

Comment: @TaylorCochran: Oh, I am sorry for the confusion, the "distribution" in np.round() is incorrect. It is actually "data", so I am rounding the "data" generated in the earlier step. I have now corrected it in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237904/discussion-between-s-d-and-taylor-cochran).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of skewed distributions, an infinite number in fact. If you want one with guarantees on the min and max, a simple and easy-to-generate possibility is the [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution). Triangles are parameterized by specifying the min, max, and mode (most likely outcome). Any value for mode other than the mid-point between min and max will yield skewness. If you want results that are right-skewed between 1 and 10, use values like 1, 10, and 3 as the min, max, and mode, respectively.

Triangular distributions are available through the [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) or [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.triangular.html).

If the triangular distribution is too piecewise linear and pointy for you, another alternative might be the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). Betas are defined on the range [0,1], so you would need to scale and shift to get other ranges.

The beta distribution is available through [numpy/scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Yes it does. I had seen triangular distribution but I was not sure about it. I experimented with different min, max and modes and saw the different distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer.

Comment: Check out the help center's [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and Q&A about [why voting is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.